# Split each PDF page in two?

Tags: pdf, layout, pdf-generation, split

I have a large number of PDF files which have two slides to a page (for printing).

The format is A4 pages each with two slides setup like so:

```
-----------
| slide 1 |
-----------
| slide 2 |
-----------
```

**How can I generate a new PDF file with one slide per page?**

Happy to use GUI, CLI, scripts or even interface with a language's PDF library; but I do need the text on the slides to still be selectable.

Comment: Finally found a tool, it's called: "[**PDF Scissors**](http://www.pdfscissors.com/)"

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/235074/35237

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[**PDF Scissors**](https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/) allowed me to bulk split (crop) all pages in a PDF.

Comment: Promising, but needs Java :(

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I fixed the dead link :)

Answer (score 18):

`mutool` works brillantly for this.  The example below will chop each page of `input.pdf` into 3 horizontal and 8 vertical parts (thus creating 24 pages of output for each 1 of input):

```
mutool poster -x 3 -y 8 input.pdf output.pdf
```

To install `mutool`, just install [`mupdf`](http://www.mupdf.com), which is probably packaged with most GNU/Linux distributions.

(Credits to [marttt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179398/26952).)

On debian based linux systems like ubuntu, you can install it using

```
sudo apt install mupdf
sudo apt install mupdf-tools
```

Comment: mutool is a very powerful little program. I recommend taking a look at it's manual page (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mutool.1.html).

Comment: When I tried using this command (in my case mutool poster -y 2 input.pdf output.pdf) the resulting output.pdf had its pages sorted incorrectly. Is there any way to fix this? I couldn't find it in the man page

Comment: @kaslusimoes I guess your input file orientation is not consistent with `mutool` expectations, in which case you could just use e.g. `pdf180` (from `pdfjam`) on your input file before feeding `mutool` with it.  If on the other hand your input file ordering is more complicated, you could just resort pages manually with `mutool clean input.pdf output.pdf 2,1,3,4,6,5` where `2,1,3,4,6,5` is the new ordering you'd like.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a Python library called PyPDF. This function will split double pages no matter what the page orientation is:

```py
import copy
import math
import pyPdf

def split_pages(src, dst):
    src_f = file(src, 'r+b')
    dst_f = file(dst, 'w+b')

    input = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(src_f)
    output = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(input.getNumPages()):
        p = input.getPage(i)
        q = copy.copy(p)
        q.mediaBox = copy.copy(p.mediaBox)

        x1, x2 = p.mediaBox.lowerLeft
        x3, x4 = p.mediaBox.upperRight

        x1, x2 = math.floor(x1), math.floor(x2)
        x3, x4 = math.floor(x3), math.floor(x4)
        x5, x6 = math.floor(x3/2), math.floor(x4/2)

        if x3 > x4:
            # horizontal
            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x5, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)

            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x5, x2)
        else:
            # vertical
            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x6)

            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x6)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)

        output.addPage(p)
        output.addPage(q)

    output.write(dst_f)
    src_f.close()
    dst_f.close()
```

Comment: any idea why this is producing an empty file with python 2.7 and pypdf 1.13? thanks!

Comment: Why does `math.floor()` is needed here?

Answer (score 11):

[Briss](http://briss.sourceforge.net/) is "a simple cross-platform (Linux, Windows, Mac OSX) application for cropping PDF files. A simple user interface lets you define exactly the crop-region by fitting a rectangle on the visually overlaid pages." It's open source (GPL).

Works well for me. The GUI is minimal, but functional. It can also be used from the command line.

Comment: They had to go ahead and call it Bris didn't they `>.<`! - Cheers, I'll check it out :)

Comment: Love you man, it worked!. I had to split in 4 my pages, and this just did the trick!

Comment: Use this! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Matt Gumbley for his Python Script. I have modified that Python script such that it now also works with PDFs that contain portrait and landscape pages and cropped pages:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Feb 26 08:49:39 2015

@author: Matt Gumbley  (stackoverflow)
changed by Hanspeter Schmid to deal with already cropped pages
"""

import copy
import math
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def split_pages2(src, dst):
    src_f = file(src, 'r+b')
    dst_f = file(dst, 'w+b')

    input = PdfFileReader(src_f)
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(input.getNumPages()):
        # make two copies of the input page
        pp = input.getPage(i)
        p = copy.copy(pp)
        q = copy.copy(pp)
        
        # the new media boxes are the previous crop boxes
        p.mediaBox = copy.copy(p.cropBox)
        q.mediaBox = copy.copy(p.cropBox)
                
        x1, x2 = p.mediaBox.lowerLeft
        x3, x4 = p.mediaBox.upperRight
        
        x1, x2 = math.floor(x1), math.floor(x2)
        x3, x4 = math.floor(x3), math.floor(x4)
        x5, x6 = x1+math.floor((x3-x1)/2), x2+math.floor((x4-x2)/2)

        if (x3-x1) > (x4-x2):
            # horizontal
            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x5, x4)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)

            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x5, x2)
        else:
            # vertical
            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x6)

            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x6)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)


        p.artBox = p.mediaBox
        p.bleedBox = p.mediaBox
        p.cropBox = p.mediaBox

        q.artBox = q.mediaBox
        q.bleedBox = q.mediaBox
        q.cropBox = q.mediaBox
        
        output.addPage(q)
        output.addPage(p)
        

    output.write(dst_f)
    src_f.close()
    dst_f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it with `pdfrw`:

```py
import sys, os, pdfrw
writer = pdfrw.PdfWriter()
for page in pdfrw.PdfReader('input.pdf').pages:
    for y in [0, 0.5]:
        newpage = pdfrw.PageMerge()    
        newpage.add(page, viewrect=(0, y, 1, 0.5))
        writer.addpages([newpage.render()])
writer.write('output.pdf')
```

Short and working!

If you want it rotated (example: input A4 portrait, output 2 A5 portrait and not landscape):

```py
import sys, os, pdfrw
writer = pdfrw.PdfWriter()
for page in pdfrw.PdfReader('input.pdf').pages:
    for y in [0, 0.5]:
        newpage = pdfrw.PageMerge()    
        newpage.add(page, viewrect=(0, y, 1, 0.5))
        p = newpage.render()
        p.Rotate = 270
        writer.addpages([p])
writer.write('output.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try [BRISS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/).
>
> [image]
>
> It lets you split each page into as many subpages as you want by
>   defining regions with a GUI. It groups all similar pages into groups
>   for you, so you can define regions for that group once.
>
> It's cross-platform, free, and open-source.

(copy-pasted from https://superuser.com/a/235327/35237)

Answer (score 0):

If using a Java or .Net library is ok for you, you can use iText / iTextSharp.

An example for tiling an existing document can be found in the book iText in Action, 2nd edition, in the freely available [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf): [TilingHero.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=116) / [TilingHero.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=TilingHero).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the resulting PDF looked fine in Adobe Reader and Mac preview, but did not appear to have been split into separate pages at all when viewing on iOS.

I used Python 2.7.8 and PyPDF2, and modified the script as follows, which worked fine (and reordered the pages left/right, rather than right/left).

```py
import copy
import math
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def split_pages(src, dst):
    src_f = file(src, 'r+b')
    dst_f = file(dst, 'w+b')

    input = PdfFileReader(src_f)
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(input.getNumPages()):
        p = input.getPage(i)
        q = copy.copy(p)
        q.mediaBox = copy.copy(p.mediaBox)

        x1, x2 = p.mediaBox.lowerLeft
        x3, x4 = p.mediaBox.upperRight

        x1, x2 = math.floor(x1), math.floor(x2)
        x3, x4 = math.floor(x3), math.floor(x4)
        x5, x6 = math.floor(x3/2), math.floor(x4/2)

        if x3 > x4:
            # horizontal
            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x5, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)

            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x5, x2)
        else:
            # vertical
            p.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x4)
            p.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x6)

            q.mediaBox.upperRight = (x3, x6)
            q.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (x1, x2)

        p.artBox = p.mediaBox
        p.bleedBox = p.mediaBox
        p.cropBox = p.mediaBox
    
        q.artBox = q.mediaBox
        q.bleedBox = q.mediaBox
        q.cropBox = q.mediaBox

        output.addPage(q)
        output.addPage(p)

    output.write(dst_f)
    src_f.close()
    dst_f.close()
```

Comment: any idea why this is producing an empty file with python 2.7 and pypdf 1.13? thanks!

Comment: Why does `math.floor()` is needed here?

Comment: there is mismatch in insertion order of created pages. It should be 
`output.addPage(p)` and then `output.addPage(q)`
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is Hanspeter Schmid answer updated to python 3.10.9 and PyPDF2 3.0.1:

```
import copy
import math
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def split_pages2(src, dst):
    with open(src, 'r+b') as src_f, open(dst, 'w+b') as dst_f:

        input = PdfReader(src_f)
        output = PdfWriter()

        for i in range(len(input.pages)):
            # make two copies of the input page
            pp = input.pages[i]
            p = copy.copy(pp)
            q = copy.copy(pp)
            
            # the new media boxes are the previous crop boxes
            p.mediabox = copy.copy(p.cropbox)
            q.mediabox = copy.copy(p.cropbox)
                    
            x1, x2 = p.mediabox.lower_left
            x3, x4 = p.mediabox.upper_right
            
            x1, x2 = math.floor(x1), math.floor(x2)
            x3, x4 = math.floor(x3), math.floor(x4)
            x5, x6 = x1+math.floor((x3-x1)/2), x2+math.floor((x4-x2)/2)

            if (x3-x1) > (x4-x2):
                # horizontal
                q.mediabox.upper_right = (x5, x4)
                q.mediabox.lower_left= (x1, x2)

                p.mediabox.upper_right = (x3, x4)
                p.mediabox.lower_left = (x5, x2)
            else:
                # vertical
                p.mediabox.upper_right = (x3, x4)
                p.mediabox.lower_left= (x1, x6)

                q.mediabox.upper_right = (x3, x6)
                q.mediabox.lower_left= (x1, x2)


            p.artbox = p.mediabox
            p.bleedbox = p.mediabox
            p.cropbox = p.mediabox

            q.artbox = q.mediabox
            q.bleedbox = q.mediabox
            q.cropbox = q.mediabox
            
            output.add_page(q)
            output.add_page(p)
            

        output.write(dst_f)
        src_f.close()
        dst_f.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

With `mupdf-1.8-windows-x64`, in win10 CMD, you need to have '**poster** ' (followed by space and without quotes) before the horizontal parameter (-x ).
For example for a double-paged scan to PDF:

> mutool poster -x 2 -y 1 C:\Users\alfie\Documents\SNM\The_Ultimate_Medicine.pdf C:\Users\alfie\Documents\ebooks\The_Ultimate_Medicine.pdf

What a wonderful tool! Merci infiniment !..
(and the output file ~9MB is only 52KB bigger than the original!)